# how to disable button in spesific day in php javascript

Tags: codeigniter

for example I have 7 buttons, I will make sure button's disable in specific day with different days. How to achieve this?

```
<input type ="submit" class="day1" id="day1">button1

<input type ="submit" class="day2" id="day2">button2

<input type ="submit" class="day3" id="day3">button3

<input type ="submit" class="day4" id="day4">button4

<input type ="submit" class="day5" id="day5">button5

<input type ="submit" class="day6" id="day6">button6

<input type ="submit" class="day7" id="day7">button7
```

Comment: what are these days? are they hardcoded. Your requirement is not clear.

Comment: which are specific day ? please explain more in detail

Comment: if button1 is sun, wed, thu
button2 is mon, tue, fri
ext.
that day is from database

Answer (score 0):

You can get current date and day in php or javascript and disable the button (add condition) as per the your requirement in php or javascript also.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code, i hope it's work.

```
// Numeric representation of the day of the week,  0=sunday,1=monday
$dayOfWeek = date('w',time());


<input type ="submit" class="day1" id="day1" <?php echo $dayOfWeek==0?'disabled':''?>>button1
```

Comment: if i want to maybe 1 button have any days, that's code can be?